# Create a zip with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I'm Trying create a Zip file with Symfony

From php documentation for ZIPArchive, I'm doing this:

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *      "/up/waka/download/",
     *      name="getEbook"
     * )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function getEbookAction()
    {

        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $filename =  "./fdgfdgdfgdf2.zip";



        if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
        }

        $zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
        $zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");


        $zip->close();

        dump($this->container, $zip);
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Front:index.html.twig')
            ->setSharedMaxAge(600);


    }
```

I return a view because a controler needs return something, I choose a view, it is for demonstration. The `dump($this->container, $zip);` returns this:

```
ZipArchive {#1764 ▼
  +"status": 12
  +"statusSys": 13
  +"numFiles": 2
  +"filename": "/var/www/html/proyectname/web/fdgfdgdfgdf2.zip"
  +"comment": ""
}
```

But, I dont see the zip file in this route. What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Which permissions has the "web" directory? Try to set it to 755

1. Check phpinfo(); if Zip is enabled
2. Check if "extension=zip.so" presents in php.ini

If both options are false, try install zip package:

```
$ pecl install zip
```

And add extension=zip.so to your php.ini manually. Restart PHP.

Comment: I check it with stat -c "%a %n" web/ and I get a 755. I try generate the zip in a Openshift server and I get the file. Is there any extension that I should install for my local version of php?

Comment: Yeah, I done it too, but I get the some status error system for ZipArchive

Comment: Try create empty .zip file manually and check if this solves your problem. Additionally, may be script doesn't like such file extension "testfilephp.txt" . time(),